# Difference btw deb and src

Tags: odoo, deb

I use the `deb file` for production and the `source` for development.Is this the correct way to do things?

I think that the deb might have certain optimizations(pyo or pyc) for production environment.

---

But since I have to move my custom modules, one at a time to the production,I find it increasingly difficult.

The actual addons path is here

```
(1) /usr/share/pyshared/openerp/addons
```

But the init.d points to

```
(2) /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons
```

In some modules the `__init__.py` is in `1` (eg: web_rpc)

and for some its in `2` (eg: hr)

---

What the actual difference btw

```
http://nightly.openerp.com/6.1/nightly/src/
```

and

```
http://nightly.openerp.com/6.1/nightly/deb/
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the deb files, because we use the Ubuntu [all-in-one script](http://openerpappliance.com/tag/all-in-one/) from openerpappliance.com. It downloads the source from Launchpad and then runs the deployment scripts for you. It will also do updates after you've installed.

We're very happy with the 5.0 version, but we haven't tried the 6.1 version, yet.

Comment: Should try the 6.1, it has got an more efficient web interface & great features..

Comment: We're in the middle of migrating now, @Jibin.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with 6.1 is you can give multiple addons path to the your config file in comma separated , or else you can create link in addons folder for your customized folder while you can keep cumized module where you want, just put link(shortcut) to the addon sfoderl of your. this will give you flexibility.

Thank YOu

Comment: Thanks.But I am customizing some of the built-in modules, directly without inheriting(I know its not recommended). I move(overwrite) the files to `/usr/share/pyshared/openerp/addons` after development.

Comment: ok src is basically a source file which like ready for development extract and run from wherever you want. While Deb are ready to deploy package you can install them like system service and it is one lick installation on system like Debian, Ubuntu.

Comment: I am sorry but What Optimization you talking about ?? Are you trying to say that Improvements done by you  ??

Comment: No.I am asking is there any optimization done for production environment in the deb (except installing as a service) ?